# Connect my Activity, Service and BroadcastListener

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Developing my first Android app at the moment.  I'm new to Android, but did a bit of Java in University.  PHP, JavaScript, C# and my employers proprietary language (not unlike BASIC) are my background so I do have a good programming understanding.

The plan is:

- An `Acticity` with a toggle button - when on it starts the service (below).
- A `Service` that will sit in the background and listen for data on a specific TCP port.
- A `BroadcastReceiver` that will monitor the WiFi status.

I have all three in place - but can't seem to figure out how to connect them!

The `Service` should be able to send data back to the `Activity`.  The `Service` should also stop if the `Activity` is terminated (but not if it is just closed - only if the app is terminated.

The `BroadcastReceiver` should be able to stop the service and update the `Activity` if the WiFi changes to disconnected.

At the moment all three work semi independently of each other.  The `Activity` can stop and start the `Service` no bother.  The `BroadcastReceiver` will show a `Toast` message if the WiFi is disconnected.  Its just the inter-communication I'm not sure of.

The app is a personal project and I will be open sourcing it when complete.  As such I'm more than happy to share the current code with anyone who can assist.  It's at http://www.tip2tail.co.uk/files/android_code.zip

Any help is appreciated :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) explaination. You can bind to a service and call methods from it.

```
Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
bindService(it, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Bind to the service in each activity so you can do whatever you want with it.
Don't forget to unbind in your activity its' onDestroy.

```
if(mBound)unbindService(mConnection);
```

And simply stop the service by calling.

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

This is the serviceConnection I use.

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;            
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

Place this in your service to return itself to the activity:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

Finally, this will be called after starting your service `startService(intent);`
Note that it returns `Service.START_STICKY`. This will prevent your service from being killed, unless the OS has very little memory.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {      
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

I hope my answere will help you and good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks @robin!  So say I had a method in the `Activity` called `doSomething(String sText)` and I wanted to call it from the `Service` would i have to reconnect the `LocalBinder` etc?  I'm still not sure I'm getting this! :(

Comment: I would not call methods from a activity. The activity could be destroyed. Place those methods in your service. You can call methods from the service because you pass the service back to the activity mService = binder.getService();

Comment: Second. unbinding the service does not mean destroying it. When a activty is bound to a service, it is almost stuck with it. By unbinding, the activty can be destroyed safely. You can always rebind to a service. Note a service can not be started twice, so don't worry about that.

Comment: Ahhhh OK.  So the Activity call methods on the Service but not the other way around.  Thats fine.  Well stage one done.  Still need to get the BroadcastReceiver to tell the service to stop too.

Comment: I think the is a misunderstanding. Do not call methods that are placed in the activity.

Comment: Sorry I understood you but my fingers were typing something different ;-)  I have edited the above comment.

Comment: The otherway around is possible ofcourse, but I would simply not do it.